# vb - edit specific cell on double click and set read only after

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio

I am developing simple app in visual basic and what I want to do is:

On load whole `DataGridView1` is `ReadOnly`

Next if user will double click on cell, then it turns edit mode for that cell
I try to do this by:

```
   Private Sub CellDouble(ByVal sender As Object,
        ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

        DataGridView1(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).ReadOnly = False

        DataGridView1.BeginEdit(e.RowIndex)

    End Sub
```

But it doesnt even react. (function is triggered but code not working)

Final step is to Set Read only back to that cell after edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply did:

```
   Private Sub CellDouble(ByVal sender As Object,
        ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
        Handles DataGridView1.CellDoubleClick

        DataGridView1.BeginEdit()

    End Sub
```

and it's working fine...